# is there a single-end available bandwidth measurement tool

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, tcpip, bandwidth

i am doing my graduation thesis,currently i need a tool that is capable of measuring the
available bandwidth between client and servers.i have googled that, the link
http://www.icir.org/models/tools.html has many tools to do that,however,they all seem to
have to deploy the program on both of the two ends,i.e,**the sender and the receiver**.

The problem is that i wanna measure ,for instance, the available bandwidth between my 
machine and one of the servers of **Google**, there is no way i can ssh to it and deploy 
the program(*can they permit me to do that ??*). 
So i kinda need a tool that runs **on my own end** and measure the bandwidth if the other end address is given,like

```
measurement_tool hostname_or_ipaddr_of_the_other_end
```

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You send all traffic with a probability of loss... The best way to gather loss and thus throughput statistics is to instrument both ends of a connection.  If you google "passive bandwidth measurement" you will see some reasearch techniques, but production usage relies on two sided data.

Comment: @Mike i have googled that,and it seems no such a tool,can you suggest one.

Comment: @Tracy, please post your same question on [CS Theory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/), you may find someone there who is able to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cloud service to rent a server for a day and test at will!
Amazon for example offers 1 year free of charge for a "micro-instance" server, that's a good start.
I personally use 'iperf'.